# C# Custom Action Linq to XML vs XmlConfig/XmlFile

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I would like to know what are pros and cons between C# Custom action and util extention when creating/changing xml.

From my experience-

C# Custom action : Using LINQ to XML and XmlReader is more common than using wix syntax. It will be more convenient to change the code for non wix user.

XmlConfig/XmlFile : No need to know c# in order to change xml. Great for non programers and small msi packages.

Hope to here more advantage for both capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)If you are writing managed code,you have to handle rollback and uninstall scenarios.

If you are using WIX code, rollback and uninstall scenarios will be handled by Installer.

2)But you don't have much control like in managed code i.e. you are bounded by what WIX toolset provides.

3)And don't forget shared resources. Most of the time, changes made by managed code in shared resources do not increase shared resource reference counter.
While changes made using WIX installer,takes care of this issue.

---

And there would be many more such differences.As much as possible try to use WIX  features and use custom actions only if WIX dont have that feature or have bugs implementing that solution.

Answer (score 1):

main difference is in the imperative and declarative paradigms of programming
as WiX prefers declarative style - extensions are preferable way

secondly - if you write own CA's (managed or unmanaged) you have to handle repair/rollback/uninstall seqs (it's done in UtilExt)